# Data sent by firefox to google's safebrowsing APIs

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, protocol-buffers, safe-browsing, safe-browsing-api

I'm trying to debug what data is sent by firefox to google's safe browsing APIs.

So far, I was able to tap into the request sent, which looks something like:

```
https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatListUpdates:fetch?$ct=application/x-protobuf&key=AIzaSyC7jsptDS3am4tPx4r3nxis7IMjBc5Dovo&$httpMethod=POST&$req=ChUKE25hdmNsaWVudC1hdXRvLWZmb3gaJwgFEAQaGwoNCAUQBhgBIgMwMDEwARCk1QkaAhgKsy218SICIAIoARonCAEQBBobCg0IARAGGAEiAzAwMTABENeOCBoCGAr-a4NBIgIgAigBGicIAxAEGhsKDQgDEAYYASIDMDAxMAEQ_JYIGgIYCtVt0KUiAiACKAEaJwgHEAQaGwoNCAcQBhgBIgMwMDEwARDcuAgaAhgKOQYHqCICIAIoARolCAkQBBoZCg0ICRAGGAEiAzAwMTABEB8aAhgKNd1EeSICIAIoAQ==
```

or

```
https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/fullHashes:find?$ct=application/x-protobuf&key=AIzaSyC7jsptDS3am4tPx4r3nxis7IMjBc5Dovo&$httpMethod=POST&$req=ChUKE25hdmNsaWVudC1hdXRvLWZmb3gSGwoNCAUQBhgBIgMwMDEwARCq1QkaAhgGlctYrBouCAUQBBoGCgTnIr_kGgYKBDB7AsgaBgoEcj_bPBoGCgScmzMmGgYKBMkwXGMgAQ==
```

How do i figure out what the plain text payload is?

So far using the stacktrace it looks like the payload is encoded using

```
https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/url-classifier/UrlClassifierListManager.jsm#591
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

## This is literally my first post

Anyways, I saw this today while using cypress, I don't think it's anything to worry about. This is a stretch but have you considered the "==" at the end of the url, isn't that base64?

I plugged your

```
ChUKE25hdmNsaWVudC1hdXRvLWZmb3gSGwoNCAUQBhgBIgMwMDEwARCq1QkaAhgGlctYrBouCAUQBBoGCgTnIr_kGgYKBDB7AsgaBgoEcj_bPBoGCgScmzMmGgYKBMkwXGMgAQ==
```

into `https://www.base64decode.org` and got this back: `navclient-auto-ffox`, along with other junk characters, try the decoder if you really need to see them.

Might as we'll quickly checkout `navclient-auto-ffox` on google, weird enough it replaced my search string with `?navclient-auto-ffox??`, whatever, the first site to come up is:

```
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.safebrowsing.provider.%2A.updateURL
```

and I quote:

##### Possible values and their effects

The URL from which blacklist information is retrieved.

###### By default

The following preference and value exists: `browser.safebrowsing.provider.0.updateURL`:

- `http://sb.google.com/safebrowsing/update?client={moz:client}&appver={moz:version}`

###### In trunk builds:

`browser.safebrowsing.provider.0.updateURL`:

- `http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client={moz:client}&appver={moz:version}&pver=2.1`

(The string `{moz:client}` is replaced by `'navclient-auto-ffox'` plus the version number for official builds. The string `{moz:version}` is replaced by the browser’s version of Gecko.)